# Is there a way to not specify namespace in kubernetes when referring to a uniquely named item?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to avoid specifying namespace if I'd like to run e.g. `kubectl describe deployment <deployment_name>` for a deployment that is unique? Or is namespace argument is always mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mandatory. The point is that `kubectl` is using the `Kubernetes` API to get information about a `deployment`.

The URL it needs to call to respond to `kubectl describe deployment <deployment_name>` is:

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{deployment_name}
```

Therefore the namespace information is needed to build the URL.

Theoretically, the `kubectl` tool could list all deployments in the cluster and retrieving the namespace but that's not the case currently (and I doubt it'll ever be).

Answer (score 4):

To list such resources, you can use [Field Selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) on name:

`kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces --field-selector='metadata.name=<deployment_name>'`

To describe:

`kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces --field-selector='metadata.name=<deployment_name>' -oyaml | kubectl describe -f -`

Answer (score 2):

When you do not use a namespace argument in a command, it is taken from active context in your `kubeconfig`. As far as I know there is no way to perform a search over other namespaces for the requested object if none is found in the current.

Though you can set the default namespace in the context. It is helpful if you are going to execute multiple commands in the same namespace. To do so:

```sh
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=<insert-namespace-name-here>
```

After that it'll use the given namespace by default.